# TypeError: user.getName is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, calendar

I am working on a project to use google Calendar API to read user's calendar events such as Work Location from a email group and push it to a shared calendar. I got the script to work only for vacations and Out of Office but not Work Locations. I would also like to modify it to display the user's name instead of the user's email username. I am very new to writing scripts and would really appreciate your help.

This is the code: // MAKE A COPY. If you try to run this script before making a copy in your own account, it won't work.

```
// To learn how to use this script, refer to the documentation:
// https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/vacation-calendar

/*
Copyright 2022 Google LLC

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

    https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
*/

// Set the ID of the team calendar to add events to. You can find the calendar's
// ID on the settings page.
let TEAM_CALENDAR_ID = 'ENTER_TEAM_CALENDAR_ID_HERE';
// Set the email address of the Google Group that contains everyone in the team.
// Ensure the group has less than 500 members to avoid timeouts.
let GROUP_EMAIL = 'ENTER_GOOGLE_GROUP_EMAIL_HERE';

let KEYWORDS = ['vacation', 'ooo', 'out of office', 'offline'];
let MONTHS_IN_ADVANCE = 3;

/**
 * Sets up the script to run automatically every hour.
 */
function setup() {
  let triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
  if (triggers.length > 0) {
    throw new Error('Triggers are already setup.');
  }
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sync').timeBased().everyHours(1).create();
  // Runs the first sync immediately.
  sync();
}

/**
 * Looks through the group members' public calendars and adds any
 * 'vacation' or 'out of office' events to the team calendar.
 */
function sync() {
  // Defines the calendar event date range to search.
  let today = new Date();
  let maxDate = new Date();
  maxDate.setMonth(maxDate.getMonth() + MONTHS_IN_ADVANCE);

  // Determines the time the the script was last run.
  let lastRun = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('lastRun');
  lastRun = lastRun ? new Date(lastRun) : null;

  // Gets the list of users in the Google Group.
  let users = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(GROUP_EMAIL).getUsers();

  // For each user, finds events having one or more of the keywords in the event
  // summary in the specified date range. Imports each of those to the team
  // calendar.
  let count = 0;
  users.forEach(function(user) {
    let username = user.getEmail().split('@')[0];
    KEYWORDS.forEach(function(keyword) {
      let events = findEvents(user, keyword, today, maxDate, lastRun);
      events.forEach(function(event) {
        importEvent(username, event);
        count++;
      }); // End foreach event.
    }); // End foreach keyword.
  }); // End foreach user.

  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('lastRun', today);
  console.log('Imported ' + count + ' events');
}

/**
 * Imports the given event from the user's calendar into the shared team
 * calendar.
 * @param {string} username The team member that is attending the event.
 * @param {Calendar.Event} event The event to import.
 */
function importEvent(username, event) {
  event.summary = '[' + username + '] ' + event.summary;
  event.organizer = {
    id: TEAM_CALENDAR_ID,
  };
  event.attendees = [];
  console.log('Importing: %s', event.summary);
  try {
    Calendar.Events.import(event, TEAM_CALENDAR_ID);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error attempting to import event: %s. Skipping.',
        e.toString());
  }
}

/**
 * In a given user's calendar, looks for occurrences of the given keyword
 * in events within the specified date range and returns any such events
 * found.
 * @param {Session.User} user The user to retrieve events for.
 * @param {string} keyword The keyword to look for.
 * @param {Date} start The starting date of the range to examine.
 * @param {Date} end The ending date of the range to examine.
 * @param {Date} optSince A date indicating the last time this script was run.
 * @return {Calendar.Event[]} An array of calendar events.
 */
function findEvents(user, keyword, start, end, optSince) {
  let params = {
    q: keyword,
    timeMin: formatDateAsRFC3339(start),
    timeMax: formatDateAsRFC3339(end),
    showDeleted: true,
  };
  if (optSince) {
    // This prevents the script from examining events that have not been
    // modified since the specified date (that is, the last time the
    // script was run).
    params.updatedMin = formatDateAsRFC3339(optSince);
  }
  let pageToken = null;
  let events = [];
  do {
    params.pageToken = pageToken;
    let response;
    try {
      response = Calendar.Events.list(user.getEmail(), params);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Error retriving events for %s, %s: %s; skipping',
          user, keyword, e.toString());
      continue;
    }
    events = events.concat(response.items.filter(function(item) {
      return shoudImportEvent(user, keyword, item);
    }));
    pageToken = response.nextPageToken;
  } while (pageToken);
  return events;
}

/**
 * Determines if the given event should be imported into the shared team
 * calendar.
 * @param {Session.User} user The user that is attending the event.
 * @param {string} keyword The keyword being searched for.
 * @param {Calendar.Event} event The event being considered.
 * @return {boolean} True if the event should be imported.
 */
function shoudImportEvent(user, keyword, event) {
  // Filters out events where the keyword did not appear in the summary
  // (that is, the keyword appeared in a different field, and are thus
  // is not likely to be relevant).
  if (event.summary.toLowerCase().indexOf(keyword) < 0) {
    return false;
  }
  if (!event.organizer || event.organizer.email == user.getEmail()) {
    // If the user is the creator of the event, always imports it.
    return true;
  }
  // Only imports events the user has accepted.
  if (!event.attendees) return false;
  let matching = event.attendees.filter(function(attendee) {
    return attendee.self;
  });
  return matching.length > 0 && matching[0].responseStatus == 'accepted';
}

/**
 * Returns an RFC3339 formated date String corresponding to the given
 * Date object.
 * @param {Date} date a Date.
 * @return {string} a formatted date string.
 */
function formatDateAsRFC3339(date) {
  return Utilities.formatDate(date, 'UTC', 'yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ssZ');
}
```

I made the following changes but get errors( TypeError: user.getName is not a function):

```
/**
 * Looks through the group members' public calendars and adds any
 * 'vacation' or 'out of office' events to the team calendar.
 */
function sync() {
  // Defines the calendar event date range to search.
  let today = new Date();
  let maxDate = new Date();
  maxDate.setMonth(maxDate.getMonth() + MONTHS_IN_ADVANCE);

  // Determines the time the the script was last run.
  let lastRun = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('lastRun');
  lastRun = lastRun ? new Date(lastRun) : null;

let group = GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail(GROUP_EMAIL);
let users = group.getUsers();

let count = 0;

users.forEach(function(user) {
  let name = user.getName(); // Get user's name
  let username = user.getEmail().split('@')[0];

  // Log user information
  console.log('Name: %s, Username: %s', name, username);

  KEYWORDS.forEach(function(keyword) {
    let events = findEvents(user, keyword, today, maxDate, lastRun);
    events.forEach(function(event) {
      importEvent(username, event);
      count++;
    }); // End foreach event.
  }); // End foreach keyword.
}); // End foreach user.

PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('lastRun', today);
console.log('Imported ' + count + ' events');

}

/**
 * Imports the given event from the user's calendar into the shared team
 * calendar.
 * @param {string} username The team member that is attending the event.
 * @param {Calendar.Event} event The event to import.
 */
function importEvent(username, event) {
  event.summary = '[' + username + '] ' + event.summary;
  event.organizer = {
    id: TEAM_CALENDAR_ID,
  };
  event.attendees = [];
  console.log('Importing: %s', event.summary);
  try {
    Calendar.Events.import(event, TEAM_CALENDAR_ID);
  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error attempting to import event: %s. Skipping.',
        e.toString());
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no `getName` method for `User` class. Ref: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the main problem is that you need to import your function getName() first.

I am not sure if I understood all your implementations of forEach so... just to remember, [forEach() is a method of Array instances that executes a provided function once for each array element and has no return value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).